# Where is S.M.A.R.T. data stored on a HDD?

Tags: hard-drive, smart

The S.M.A.R.T. attributes are attributes that a HDD keeps about its health and performance.

I know that the MBR is stored at C,H,S (0,0,1) which leaves no free disc space for the drive to function.

Where on the drive are the attributes stored?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I'm having trouble finding a source for it. But I'm relatively certain that the SMART data is not located on the HDD platter at all. The data is stored in a small bit of memory used by the HDD controller.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned [in this informative](http://alynjones.wordpress.com/2011/08/18/hard-disk-drives-service-area/) blog post, and as confirmation to @djg's answer, some manufacturers store some information in the service area or negative track area of a drive, while others use memory on the PCB, as mentioned by @Dracs.

Answer (score 5):

The hard drive system tracks start at track -1 and can go to track -6, depending on model. These system tracks are only accessible via the hard drive control logic and not visible to operating systems. The system tracks contain SMART data as well as other data such as serial number, etc.