# What should the expected “Power On Hours” and “Battery Usage” be for a new laptop?

Tags: laptop, battery, windows-11

My new laptop (HP Pavillion 14 series) shows “Power on Hours” as 250 hours, “Power on Count” as 95 and “Battery Usage report shows the use of battery for the last 4 days (6-7 hrs of use), whereas I purchased it just one day ago.

So, is it really a new laptop or did the store provide me the display model as new?

Also, do these attributes get deleted (like Windows logs) when I reinstall the OS or are they always intact?

Comment: Please edit your question: What is the exact make and model of laptop you purchased? In general those items would be stored on the motherboard itself and could not easily be zeroed out. If that were the case, the vendor you bought it from would do just that to hide the fact it is a lightly used machine.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The laptop has already been used.

No, reinstalling the operating system does not remove these attributes, the data is stored in a small bit of memory used by the SSD/HDD controller.

References:

[Where is S.M.A.R.T. data stored on a HDD?](https://superuser.com/questions/709371/where-is-s-m-a-r-t-data-stored-on-a-hdd)